# How to measure how many characters fit into a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a canvas and want to know how long a string can be fit into. I know this code `ctx.measureText(text)` returns the width for the text passed in. But how can I measure the other way round? If I have set all font properties and size of the canvas, how can I know how many characters can be fit?

Comment: I believe that unless you are using a monospace font, it is hard to predict what the size of the text will be. One way to handle this would be to use Binary Search like algorithm to truncate text by calculating it with `ctx.measureText(text)` each time (terminating when the optimal break point less than canvas width is obtained). [ShaveJS](https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/shave) does something similar and may be a good reference if you want to try something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a quick sample implementation over lunch break of the method I mentioned in my comment. This is a quick hack for demonstration only.. I would suggest running a few tests for edgecases.

Note: I spoofed the `ctx.measureText` for illustrative purposes.

```js
function measureText(text) {
  return text.length;
}
const ctx = {
  measureText
};

function getTruncatedText(text, width) {
  let low = 0,
    high = text.length - 1;
  let length = ctx.measureText(text);
  let truncated = '' + text;
  if (length <= width) {
    return truncated;
  }

  function recurse(low, high) {
    if ((high < low) || (low < 0) || high > text.length - 1) {
      return truncated;
    }
    let mid = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);
    truncated = text.substr(0, mid + 1);
    length = ctx.measureText(truncated);
    if (length < width) {
      low = mid + 1;
    } else if (length > width) {
      high = mid - 1;
    } else {
      return truncated;
    }
    return recurse(low, high);
  }
  return recurse(low, high);
}

console.log(getTruncatedText('1234', 1));
console.log(getTruncatedText('1234', 2));
console.log(getTruncatedText('1234', 3));
console.log(getTruncatedText('1234', 4));
console.log(getTruncatedText('1234', 5));
```